# Electrostatic boundary conditions notation

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, notation, boundary-conditions

In one book example we are trying to find the electric potential of a infinite long steel bar that is homogeneously charged that has a radius $R$. And We will be using the discontinuity of the normal component of the electric field when we cross the boundary between the inner part of the beam and the room in which it is found, basically the surface. And also the continuity of the normal component/potential is the same. In the beginning we have this:

Assuming we use the index 1 for the region inside and 2 for outside we know:

$$E_{n2}(\vec r)-E_{n1}(\vec r)= -\frac {\partial \Phi_2}{\partial n}+\frac {\partial \Phi_1}{\partial n}=\frac {\eta(\vec r)} {\epsilon_{0}}.$$

Then we have the following notation, which is called the normal derivative of the potential, exactly like above:

$\frac {\partial \Phi_i}{\partial n}|_R=\frac {\partial \Phi_o}{\partial n}|_R$, where the index "i" is for inside and the index "o" outside. I don't understand this second notation. Shouldn't there be the derivation w.r.t the normal vector (on the surface, which is $\vec n$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution:

$\vec n = \frac {\vec r} r$.Then you substitute $\partial n$ with $\partial {\frac {\vec r} r}$, cancel $1/r$ in both sides and that's how you get the 2nd expression. We also assume that outside the surface charge density is 0